# Actualizar datos con PDO

Tags: php

Tengo un problema para modificar los datos de mi tabla.

El formulario muestra los datos del registro, el problema es que al pulsar el botón actualizar, no se modifican los datos y recibo el mensaje de que no se pudo actualizar, he intentado algunos cambios pero no consigo encontrar el error, no se si tenga que ver con mis Forms.
Mi codigo es este:

```
 <?php
        if(!isset($_GET["resolucion"])) exit();
        $resolucion = $_GET["resolucion"];
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=proyecto1","root","");
        $sentencia = $pdo->prepare("SELECT resolucion, facultad, sede, carrera, asignatura, curso, regimen, fechainicio, fechafin FROM concursos WHERE resolucion = ?;");
        $sentencia->execute([$resolucion]);
        $registro = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        if($registro === FALSE){
          #No existe
        echo "¡No existe ese numero de Resolucion!";
        exit();
        }        

          ?>
```

En el Form:

```
<input value="<?php echo $registro->resolucion; ?>" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputres" name="resolucion" placeholder="Resolucion" required>
```

Aquí se actualiza los datos:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=proyecto1","root","");
        $resolucion = $_POST["resolucion"];
        $facultad = $_POST["facultad"];
        $sede = $_POST["sede"];
        $carrera = $_POST["carrera"];
        $asignatura = $_POST["asignatura"];
        $curso = $_POST["curso"];
        $regimen = $_POST["regimen"];
        $fechainicio= $_POST["fechainicio"];
        $fechafin= $_POST["fechafin"];

        $sentencia = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE concursos SET facultad = ?, sede = ?, carrera = ?, asignatura = ?, curso = ?, regimen = ?, fechainicio = ?, fechafin = ?, WHERE resolucion = ?;");
        $resultado = $sentencia->execute([$facultad, $sede, $carrera, $asignatura, $curso, $regimen, $fechainicio, $fechafin, $resolucion]); # Pasar en el mismo orden de los ?
        if($resultado === TRUE) echo "Cambios guardados";
        else echo "No se pudo actualizar. ";

 ?>
```

Comment: Estas usando `GET` y `POST`?

Comment: Que tipo de dato es `resolucion`?

Comment: Tienes un error de sintaxis aquí: `fechafin = ?, WHERE` **no debe ir coma antes del `WHERE`**. También, cuando estés depurando, en la parte del `else`  imprime el error con `print_r($pdo->errorInfo());` eso te ayudará a descubrir rápido cuál es el error. Luego cuando funcione lo quitas, pues no conviene imprimir errores internos.

Comment: En esta parte del query, puedes removar la `,`? `fechafin = ?, `

Comment: Definitivamente era un error de sintaxis antes del where. Muchas Gracias a todos!! @A.Cedano gracias, eso me falicitara con los errores, aun estoy aprendiendo!

Comment: El campo resolucion es un varchar por los tipos de datos que cargo @JonathanOrta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un error de sintaxis en tu consulta, prueba así:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=proyecto1","root","");
        $resolucion = $_POST["resolucion"];
        $facultad = $_POST["facultad"];
        $sede = $_POST["sede"];
        $carrera = $_POST["carrera"];
        $asignatura = $_POST["asignatura"];
        $curso = $_POST["curso"];
        $regimen = $_POST["regimen"];
        $fechainicio= $_POST["fechainicio"];
        $fechafin= $_POST["fechafin"];

        $sentencia = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE concursos SET facultad = ?, sede = ?, carrera = ?, asignatura = ?, curso = ?, regimen = ?, fechainicio = ?, fechafin = ? WHERE resolucion = ?;");
        $resultado = $sentencia->execute([$facultad, $sede, $carrera, $asignatura, $curso, $regimen, $fechainicio, $fechafin, $resolucion]); # Pasar en el mismo orden de los ?
        if($resultado === TRUE) echo "Cambios guardados";
        else echo "No se pudo actualizar. ";

 ?>
```

## Recomendaciones

1. Para fines de depuración puedes imprimir el mensaje de error, eso te ahorrará tiempo y muchos dolores de cabeza. Por ejemplo:

   ```
   if($resultado === TRUE) echo "Cambios guardados";
   else echo "No se pudo actualizar. ";
        print_r($pdo->errorInfo()); #No olvides quitar esto cuando funcione
   ```
2. Si alguna de las columnas del `UPDATE` no puede ser nula o vacía, verifica primero que dichas columnas no son nulas o vacías antes de mandar el `UPDATE`
3. Como control adicional podrías poner en el mensaje la cantidad de filas actualizadas con algo como esto:

   ```
   if($resultado === TRUE) echo "Cambios guardados. Filas actualizadas: {$sentencia->rowCount()}";
   ```

Comment: Excelente! Gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: @ValeriaBarrios, si te sirvió la respuesta, no olvides marcarla como aceptada.